# How to start watchApp from iPhone

Tags: apple-watch

I am developing a watch app and I want the watch app to activate when I start the app on the iPhone, but I can't find out how to do that.

The question has been asked in a number of forums and the answer has always been "Not possible", but there must be another answer as there are plenty of apps that do open the watch app automatically: Maps, Podcasts to name but two.
So what's the secret?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet. You are supposed to only use it for a workout app but on the watch side you don't really have to start HKWorkoutSession.

```
    let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    workoutConfiguration.activityType = .traditionalStrengthTraining
    workoutConfiguration.locationType = .indoor
    if WCSession.isSupported(), WCSession.default().activationState == .activated , WCSession.default().isWatchAppInstalled{
        healthStore.startWatchApp(with: workoutConfiguration, completion: { (success, error) in
            print(error.debugDescription)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not getting past  WCSession.default().activationState == .activated.. Suspect because the watch app isn't running.

Comment: Actually, not getting past WCSession.default().isWatchAppInstalled

Comment: Watch app have to be installed. If installed maybe reboot your phone and watch.

Comment: Yup, I had the app installed, and it still fails after rebooting watch and phone. ( I had to add HealthKit permissions to the phone app) 
I still don't understand the mechanism, sorry. In your code, startWatchApp depends on WCSession.default().isWatchAppInstalled, but I don't understand how that can return true if the watchApp is not already running ...???

Even with the watchapp running and communicating with the phone (by sending data being displayed on the phone) I can't get isWatchAppInstalled to return true.

Comment: isWatchAppIntalled is pretty self-explanatory. You can bypass the check to see your watch app open.

Comment: I'm not finding it that self-explanatory at all, sorry.  
As I say above, I can't get isWatchAppInstalled to return true even when the watchApp is running and communicating. 
When I bypass the check, even with the watchApp running, the  success param returns "false" after a long delay - maybe 20 seconds. error is not raised.

I'm obviously missing something pretty basic here.

Comment: I wonder if we are using different versions of Swift. You used WCSession.default().activationState == .activated, which raises error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'WCSession' " in Xcode Version 9.3 (9E145).
I changed it to WCSession.default.activationState == .activated

Comment: OK, Success at last!

Once I added Workout Processing to watch extension's Info.plist Required background modes (Watch) property by checking Background Modes > Workout processing in its Capabilities.
I wonder if I'll hit problems with Apple when I try to publish my app, which is a yacht racing, not HealthKit/workout?????