# Trigger apple watch application launch from iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am creating an application for iPhone and for apple watch. I have a requirement to open the application I have created in apple watch from iPhone device. Assuming that iPhone and apple watch is paired, please suggest how this can be done in Swift code.

Comment: In short, you can't

Comment: Probably create a [launcher robot](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Butter_Robot) until apple opens up an API :D

Comment: you can open watch app if it is a workout app. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033295/how-to-start-watchapp-from-iphone